# Using the `ps` command, what does the `%cpu` column mean when having a processor with multiple cores?

Tags: php, unix, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture, ps

See the information about my CPU architecture:

```
root@jai [~]# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             16
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 86
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1541 @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               2099.998
BogoMIPS:              4199.99
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-15
```

The performance of my website was struggling, sometimes working in an intermittent manner not loading pages completely one time but then a few seconds later loading all pages fine. Totally intermittent and the same happened from different computers and phones from different locations. I suspect the problem was caused by exceeding my CPU capacity to handle the traffic and processed that I were running at that moment. So I ran the following command while I was experiencing the problem. See the results:

```
root@cup [~]# ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%cpu | more
  PID  PPID CMD                         %MEM %CPU
26468  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  1.0 57.3
26463  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  0.7 42.3
26553  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  0.6 38.5
26502  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  0.2 35.6
26190  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  0.3 29.4
18242  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  1.1 22.8
19045  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  1.0 20.6
18437  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  0.6 20.2
18269  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  1.1 18.5
18289  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  0.9 13.1
19042  1499 php-fpm: pool m_jaimemontoya_n  1.1 11.9
26906     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  7.0
 8546  8014 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=  1.1  6.7
26872     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  6.0
26877     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  6.0
26869     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  5.0
26875 21851 /usr/sbin/exim -qG           0.0  5.0
26885     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  5.0
26891     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  5.0
26895     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  5.0
26888     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  4.0
26903     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  4.0
26880 26875 /usr/sbin/exim -qG           0.0  3.0
26881 26869 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  3.0
26882 26872 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  3.0
26899 26888 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  3.0
17419  1499 php-fpm: pool jaimemontoya_com  0.0  2.5
26814     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTj-0  0.0  2.5
26849     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTk-0  0.0  2.5
21290  1499 php-fpm: pool jaimemontoya_com  0.0  2.1
14959  1499 php-fpm: pool jaimemontoya_com  0.0  2.0
16122  1499 php-fpm: pool jaimemontoya_com  0.0  2.0
17085  1499 php-fpm: pool jaimemontoya_com  0.0  2.0
22367  1499 php-fpm: pool jaimemontoya_com  0.0  2.0
26826     1 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTk-0  0.0  2.0
26859 26849 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTk-0  0.0  2.0
26884 26877 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  2.0
26902 26895 /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1jTsTl-0  0.0  2.0
18723  1499 php-fpm: pool jaimemontoya_com  0.0  1.7
21456  1499 php-fpm: pool jaimemontoya_com  0.0  1.7
21975  1499 php-fpm: pool jaimemontoya_com  0.0  1.7
13578  1499 php-fpm: pool jaimemontoya_com  0.0  1.6
```

I am trying to understand how to interpret the `%CPU` column. If I add up the following values, I get 404.2 as the total:

```
57.3+42.3+38.5+35.6+29.4+22.8+20.6+20.2+18.5+13.1+11.9+7.0+6.7+6.0+5.0+5.0+5.0+5.0+5.0+4.0+4.0+3.0+3.0+3.0+2.5+2.5+2.5+2.1+2.0+2.0+2.0+2.0+2.0+2.0+2.0+2.0+1.7+1.7+1.7+1.6
```

Considering that I have 16 CPUs, how can I interpret that `404.2` that results after adding up all of the values in the `%CPU` column for all processes? I have a server with 30 GB RAM with 8 Core / 16 Thread CPU. Thank you.

NOTE: In the past I used to get this warning frequently on my server logs: `WARNING: [pool m_jaimemontoya_com] server reached max_children setting (5), consider raising it` So I raised it to 32. For that reason, you see more than 5 processed for `php-fpm` running simultaneously.

**UPDATE 1:**

Using `man lscpu`, I see this:

```
COLUMNS
       CPU    The logical CPU number of a CPU as used by the Linux kernel.
```

Comment: That's a bad data point for `ps` CPU% is _CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process_.  Might look at `top` or other utility.

Comment: Percentage of a single core used. 8 cores = 800%, and 400% consumed would be 50% of the overall total.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Wow, the `top` was all I needed! Thank you and next time I know what to use! It looks like the `Ctrl+Alt+Sup` and then then `Task Manager` of Windows.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Cool. I needed to know that. Please write it as an answer to have this question marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked AbraCadaver to write his comment as an answer because that was the solution for me. He did not do it. I am copying his comment below as the answer to my question:

"That's a bad data point for `ps` CPU% is CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process. Might look at `top` or other utility. – AbraCadaver Apr 29 at 20:41"